# What structure is "give it a read"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality

What kind of grammatical structure is "give it a listen"? We hear and use these kind of grammatical structures a lot in which a verb is preceded by an article. I have heard that verb cannot precede an article.

This structure is: Verb + subject + article + verb.

Examples:

1. Give it a go
2. Give it a listen
3. Give it a read etc

All these are the examples of the structure I described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Give [x] a try*" is a *verb phrase* or *phrasal verb*. Even though one might say "Give it a go!" as a complete sentence, that is an *order*, just as someone might say "Try it!" or even just "Go!".

Other examples of phrasal verbs:

- Blow it up
- Ask her over
- Break it down
- Bring it up

Answer (score 0):

"(You), give it a go."

'You' is the subject.
'it' is the indirect object.

Google says 'go', in this case, is a noun.

'go'
noun
1.
INFORMAL
an attempt or trial at something.
"have a go at answering the questions yourself"

'go' is the direct object.

In this example, there is hence no verb preceded by an article.